# Is it possible to deactive comma , in maths so we can write 3,1416 without 3{,}1416 or siunitx \num{3,1416}?

Tags: number, decimal-number

Is it possible to deactive comma `,` in maths so in Spanish (for example) we can write `3,1416` without `3{,}1416` or `siunitx`  `\num{3,1416}`?

Comment: Put `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}` after `\usepackage{siunitx}` for `\num{3,1416}` to output with a comma. Unsure about math mode though

Comment: Are you looking for the `icomma` package? With this package you can directly write `3,1416`

Comment: Amazing list!  I love LaTeX/Tikz.  I've been using LaTeX since 1989. If only I had had this lovely list then!!  Thank you